# Best practice for dropping Pandas dataframe columns / rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I recently learned that it is possible to use the `iloc` function for dropping columns and rows of dataframe objects (as detailed in this [Tutorial](https://thispointer.com/drop-first-row-of-pandas-dataframe-3-ways/)); for example, to drop the zeroth row of a dataframe we can write `df = df.iloc[1: , :]`.

At work I often need to drop columns or rows by index, so the `iloc` function seems easier to use than Pandas' prepackaged `drop` function. However, is there any drawback in using the first method?

Comment: You can do `df.drop(df.index[index_number])` too. Note that the behavior will be different depending on whether or not the index values are unique.

Comment: `drop` is best if you're removing values by label and you don't necessarily know where in the DataFrame they appear. If you're removing/subsetting by position there are no issues with `iloc` and often _much_ more readable that `drop`